# Wired connection on 18.04 keeps connecting and disconnecting

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have a fresh installation of **Ubuntu 18.04** from a bootable USB.
My motherboard **PRIME Z390-A** has an **Intel I219-V Gigabit LAN** network card.
I've been trying to fix this for several days now, and it's been extremely annoying, as this motherboard doesn't have WiFi.

**Ethernet cable works with laptop** (both Windows and Ubuntu).
In network settings I can see that there is a Wired connection and its **status keeps alternating between "Connecting - 100Mb/s" and "Cable unplugged"** (despite the cable being plugged in all this time).

I've found several similar threads, but none of the fixes worked for me. In particular, I tried rebooting the computer and the router, restarting the network service, going to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and
changing the line managed=false to managed=true, running a different Ubuntu version (16.04), and running the live installation from bootable pendrive, none of which fixed the issue.

**Here are the outputs of some of the typical commands that were requested in those threads:**

**1. dmesg | grep e100**

```
$ dmesg | grep e100
[    1.430346] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.430346] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.430476] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set 
to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.634976] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.703178] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 04:92:26:c3:b1:67
[    1.703179] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.703237] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.703760] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   18.339438] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   18.339445] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   19.140294] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[   22.031793] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   22.031795] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   22.824304] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[   25.571979] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   25.571986] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   26.368188] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[   85.064039] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   85.064046] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   85.848304] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
```

And so on...

**2. ip -c a**

```
ip -c a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 04:92:26:c3:b1:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**3. lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2**

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [1043:8672]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

**4. systemctl status NetworkManager.service --no-pager -l**

```
systemctl status NetworkManager.service --no-pager -l
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-03-03 14:38:32 CET; 1h 12min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 840 (NetworkManager)
   Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
       └─840 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

mar 03 15:50:41 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624641.4199] device (eno1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 03 15:50:41 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624641.4201] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mar 03 15:50:41 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624641.4210] dhcp4 (eno1): dhclient started with pid 4113
mar 03 15:50:41 janek-ubuntu dhclient[4113]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x55484130)
mar 03 15:50:44 janek-ubuntu dhclient[4113]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x55484130)
mar 03 15:50:44 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624644.9622] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
mar 03 15:50:51 janek-ubuntu dhclient[4113]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x55484130)
mar 03 15:50:51 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624651.9679] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mar 03 15:50:52 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624652.0003] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 4113
mar 03 15:50:52 janek-ubuntu NetworkManager[840]: <info>  [1551624652.0003] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> done
```

I will be happy to provide additional context and command outputs.
It's hard to come up with an idea what to do next.

Comment: You've got a 1G network controller only connecting at 100M. You've either got a bad cable/switch/hub/router. What happens if you connect from the computer DIRECTLY to your cable/dsl modem? How is this all wired together?

Comment: The router is a modem as well I think, there is nothing else I can connect it to I'm afraid: https://www.upc.ch/pdf/support/manuals/en/internet/ConnectBox/connect-box-manual.pdf

Comment: Reset "/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and changing the line managed=true" back to false. Try a **different ethernet cable**, and connect it to a **different yellow port** on the back of the modem/router. **Power cycle everything**. Retry. Check connection speed. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Hey @heynnema I tried a different cable and it took a while but it did connect in the end! Moreover, when we switched back to the other cable, it also worked now! 
Thank you very much :) Please make an answer and I will accept it. What just happened?

Comment: Unfortunately, its working on the "worse" cable was short-lived and now it's back to the plugging - unplugged cycle... since it worked on the short "better" one (and it was 1000 Mb/s), it seems your diagnosis was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

The existing configuration was only connecting at 100M, with frequent disconnects, and the ethernet interface is 1G. This is a sure giveaway that there's a potential cable problem.

We switched out the cable, and it's now working at 1G.

Comment: unbelievably worked for me too